# Quick flashing prompt when executing ideavim keymap in Webstorm

Tags: intellij-idea, ideavim

When I execute a keymap defined in my `.ideavim` such as this:

```
nnoremap <leader>gf :action GotoFile<cr>
```

the popup flashes quickly and goes away. (This occurs 95% of the time and once in awhile it stays up as expected.  I tried many combinations of typing slow/quick and found no pattern that tends to cause it to happen more.)

If I use <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, it pops up and waits for my input as expected.

Any suggestions on how to debug or fix this so the prompt/popup stays up?

Additional info:

- I am running XFCE4 (Debian-Jessie) and not sure if there is some fight for window focus.  My XFCE configuration is pretty vanilla out of the box though. I already played with *Window Manager > Focus* and *Window Manager Tweaks* settings too...
- In Webstorm's *Settings > Other Settings > Vim Emulation*, I set the Handler for most items to `vim`.
- Webstorm version:

  ```
  WebStorm 2016.1.3
  Build #WS-145.1616, built on May 27, 2016
  JRE: 1.8.0_91-b14 amd64
  JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM by Oracle Corporation
  ```
- Note: I am not using OpenJDK. (The problem occurs with OpenJDK to, but I switched after reading [WebStorm in XFCE/Xmonad – JetBrains Support](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207024095-WebStorm-in-XFCE-Xmonad) with the hope it would be fixed. Unfortunately this problem persists for me though.)

Update: I almost resolved the issue by going to Webstorm's *Settings > Appearance & Behavior > Appearance* and unchecking "*Hide navigation popups on focus loss*".  This prevents the flashing popup. However now the focus isn't on the popup.  Any ideas of what is stealing the focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is fixed in EAP builds of IdeaVim. Try https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim#get-an-early-access.

Comment: Thanks! I am happy to hear it was a known problem and fixed.  I confirm it fixes the problem.